# Python: Create a sentence from a list of words (there should be no spaces before comma and period)

Tags: python, string, list

The desired output: *If nobody loved him, he probably struggled to love himself.*

```
words = ["if", "nobody", "loved", "him", ",", "he", "probably", "struggled", "to", "love", "himself", "."]

for i in range(len(words)):
    if words[i] == "." or ",":
        continue
    sentence = " ".join(words)

print(sentence.capitalize())
```

However, it doesn't work. How do I reach for commas and periods in a list?

Comment: A [mre] is not just broken code & specification. Say why the code should work & find the first point where the state isn't what you expect & show it & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex, you simply need to put the chars that don't need a space, into the bracket `[.,;]`, this is easier to handle new cases, and shorter so

```
import re
words = ["if", "nobody", "loved", "him", ",", "he", "probably", "struggled", "to", "love", "himself", "."]

sentence = re.sub(r"(?: ([.,;]))", r"\g<1>", " ".join(words))

print(sentence)
```

The regex `(?: ([.,;]))` match a space followed by one of the char inside the bracket, and replace by this char only (without the space so)

Answer (score 0):

use `replace` to fix period and comma

```
words = ["if", "nobody", "loved", "him", ",", "he", "probably", "struggled", "to", "love", "himself", "."]

for i in range(len(words)):
    if words[i] == "." or ",":
        continue
sentence = (" ".join(words)).replace(' .','.').replace(' ,',',') # use replace to fix period and comma

print(sentence.capitalize())
```

```
If nobody loved him, he probably struggled to love himself.
```

Comment: Why do you keep the loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) along with `replace()`:

```
words = ["if", "nobody", "loved", "him", ",", "he", "probably", "struggled", "to", "love", "himself", "."]

print(" ".join(w for w in words).replace(" ,", ",").replace(" .", ".").capitalize())
```

OUTPUT:

```
If nobody loved him, he probably struggled to love himself.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `words[i] == "." or ","` will always be True. So you always step into `continue` which is the reason you can not print anything. You should change it to `word == "." or word == ","`

Second, you can just Iterate word in a loop.

Correct code:

```
words = ["if", "nobody", "loved", "him", ",", "he", "probably", "struggled", "to", "love", "himself", "."]

sentence = ""
for word in words:
    if word == "." or word == ",":
        sentence += word
    else:
        sentence += " "
        sentence += word
print(sentence.strip().capitalize())
```

Answer (score 0):

We could define rules for punctuation and then apply them while merging words one by one into an existing sentence. The advantage of defining punctuation rule is that we could then switch language in a simpler way than if the logic was hard coded.

```py
def sentence_language(punctuation_rules):

    def add_word(sentence, word):
        return sentence + punctuation_rules.get(word, f' {word}')

    def build_sentence(words):
        sentence = words[0].capitalize()
        for w in words[1:]:
            sentence = add_word(sentence, w)
        return sentence
    
    return build_sentence
```

Which we can then use that way:

```py
In [2]: en_punctuation_rules = {'.': '.', ',': ',', '!': '!', '?': '?'}
   ...: en_words = ["if", "nobody", "loved", "him", ",", "he", "probably", "struggled", "to", "love", "himself", "."]
   ...: en_sentence = sentence_language(en_punctuation_rules)
   ...: en_sentence(en_words)

"If nobody loved him, he probably struggled to love himself."
```

Or in french:

```
In [3]: fr_punctuation_rules = {'.': '.', ',': ',', '!': ' !', '?': ' ?'}
   ...: fr_words = ["si", "personne", "ne", "l'aime", ",", "comment", "pourrait-il", "s'aimer", "lui-même", "?"]
   ...: fr_sentence = sentence_language(fr_punctuation_rules)
   ...: fr_sentence(fr_words)

"Si personne ne l'aime, comment pourrait-il s'aimer lui-même ?"
```

I don't know where this could apply, but maybe some language even have a different way of separating words, if that's the case that would make sense to not hard code the spacing logic and remove the `f' {word}'` and instead use a default function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string concatenation also and another list for signs that you don't want to be in final sentence, something like this:

```
signs = ['.',',']
sentence=""

for word in words:
    if word not in signs:
    sentence = sentence + word.capitalize() + " " 
print(sentence)
```